# ORA 00904 Error:Invalid Identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

I have installed Oracle 10g in my virtual XP and created a table using

```
create table reg1 (
  fname varchar2(30),
  lname varchar2(30),
  addr varchar2(30),
  mail varchar2(30),
  occu varchar2(30),
  uname varchar2(30),
  passwd varchar2(30)
);
```

and the table created successfully.But when I am trying to fetch the values by simple query like

```
select fname, lname 
  from reg1 
 where uname="bbb";
```

I am getting error like

> ORA-00904: "bbb": invalid identifier

I cannot understand what I have done wrong here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use single quotes.

```
select fname,lname from reg1 where uname='bbb';
```

Answer (score 7):

Oracle uses double quotes `"` in order to identify cased object names. For instance the table `"test"` is not the same as the table `test`.

Strings should be enclosed by single quotes, `'`.

Making your query:

```
select fname, lname from reg1 where uname = 'bbb';
```

What's actually happening in your query is Oracle is trying to find the column `"bbb"` in the table `reg1`, as this column doesn't exist you get the error thrown.

Comment: Not just Oracle, all SQL databases